# Copying files VS not copying files?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Can someone explain to me what is the difference between ticking "copy items into destination..." and not ticking this option ?

Thank you.

Gotye.

Answer (score 3):

Selecting it will cause Xcode to copy files into your project's folder. Not selecting it will leave them where they are and use them from there - be sure not to move them in that case.